# Make every class that implements an interface call a method?

Tags: java, interface

I have in interface: `IPacket` which I use for all of the packets on my network game and I was wondering if it's possible for all classes that implement `IPacket` to automatically class a function, say `PacketRegister.registerPacket(this.getClass(), this.getPacketID())` Would be useful.

Comment: Call it when? On which instances? With what arguments?

Comment: If the class exists and implements IPacket then I went it to call registerPacket so it can be registered to a packet hashmap, is it possible to make the interface do this or will I have to call it manually?

Comment: An interface is implemented with instance methods. What instance are you invoking those methods on?

Comment: You want to register each different subclass of IPacket? Or do you want to register each instance/object of each subclass of IPacket?

Comment: I want every class which implements `IPacket` to statically call `registerPacket();`

Comment: In Java 8 you can implement default behavior in the interface definition. For Java < 8, you can *emulate* this using a base (usually abstract) class, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Make a base class and inherit all subsequent classes from it, for example:

```
public abstract class BaseClass implements IPacket {
    // Implement default behavior for IPacket
}

public class AnotherClass extends BaseClass { 
    // Already has IPacket default functionality inherited from BaseClass
}
```